# Is there a wine traditionally served with beef carpaccio?

Tags: history

Is there a wine traditionally served with beef carpaccio?

Like, they would typically serve *flammkuchen* with *federweisser*.

Comment: Dear answerers, I would like to remind everybody that food pairing suggestions are off topic on the site. I will not unilaterally close the question, since we do allow food history questions - this means though that you will have to stick to that interpretation. So please only believable explanations on whether a specific wine has been known to historically be paired with carpaccio. We moderators will have to remove answers which simply suggest wines that might go well with carpaccio, without the evidence that they were the preferred pairing.

Answer (score 4):

Beef carpaccio is a fairly recent creation.  It originated in Harry's Bar in Venice in the 1950's.  The dish is said to be base on the Piemontese dish called carne cruda all'Albese.  The Veneto and Piemonte are two different regions in northern Italy.  Different wines are produced in each region.  Given that the carpaccio is based on the Piemontese original, that is a sensible place to start.